# What is the simple form of a contraction matrix in the direction of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector v in dimension n, how to construct a n by n matrix that simply contracts or extends along the vector v but leaves any vector perpendicular to v unchanged?  What is the simplest way to construct such a matrix?   The best I could come up with was to assume the matrix in diagonalized form and set up the eigenvectors and eigenvalue. Is there easier way to do this in any dimension n? If not, May I get the general form of such matrix in 3 dimensions ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a construction similar to the one for building reflections. Split $\mathbf x$ into components $\mathbf x_\parallel+\mathbf x_\perp$ parallel to and perpendicular to $\mathbf v$. The transformation you want is then $\mathbf x \mapsto \lambda\mathbf x_\parallel+\mathbf x_\perp$. (With $\lambda=-1$ you get a reflection in the hyperplane orthogonal to $\mathbf v$.) Proceeding as with a reflection, you have $\mathbf x_\parallel = {\mathbf v^T\mathbf x \over \mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf x_\perp = \mathbf x - \mathbf x_\parallel$. Putting this all together, $$\lambda \mathbf x_\parallel + \mathbf x_\perp = \lambda \mathbf x_\parallel + \mathbf x - \mathbf x_\parallel = \mathbf x+(\lambda-1)\mathbf x_\parallel = \mathbf x + (\lambda-1){\mathbf v^T\mathbf x \over \mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\mathbf v = \left(I + (\lambda-1){\mathbf v \mathbf v^T \over \mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\right)\mathbf x.$$